# R package - Can I use global variables in the package?

Tags: r, function, global-variables, package

I am making a package on R. I have two functions sharing a variable (global).

How can I import it to the package?

For example,

```
m<-0
f<-function() { m <- m+1 }
g<-function() { m <- m-1 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you can export the variable, but you don't have to.

The topic you want to look up is "Data in packages" in the "Writing Extensions" manual.